# Open source licensing of derived works

Tags: open-source, github, mit-license, apache-license

I derived an open-sourced work, Service-Nucleus, based on Netflix's Karyon (Apache License) and Google's AngularJS (MIT License).

I want to make sure proper licensing and copyrights are in place, and I am not sure how to honor those projects and move forward legitimately at the same time.

I've researched this to some length and it's a soupy mess out there. Any advice would be greatly appreciated.

I currently provide the Apache License from NetFlix at the root.

Comment: Derived meaning cloned NetFlix/karyon, refactored it, and extended it with additional functionality. Also forked Angular-Enterprise-Seed, refactored it, and extended it significantly. So it's co-mingled with those projects - as opposed to just including (ie) maven artifacts and js scripts.

Answer (score 4):

I am not a lawyer, and this is not legal advice. You should hire an attorney who can advise you on the correct course of action. The following are, to my knowledge, the steps required to meet the requirements of both licenses.

Your software must include a relatively prominent Copyright notice that says something to the effect:

> This software includes code from: AngularJS, Copyright (C) 2010-2012 Google, Inc., and Karyon, Copyright (C) 2013 Netflix, Inc.

Then, you must also include a copy of the MIT license shipped with AngularJS (the license requires that the Copyright notice and the license's warranty notice are both included in all copies) and the Apache License from Karyon (which also requires a notice of the Copyright and the warranty disclaimer). Both of these licenses should be copied, in full, into a file called `NOTICES` included in your project.

You are free to distribute the code under whatever open source license you see fit, not including the GPL or LGPL versions 1 or 2, or any other similar Copyleft license (GPLv3 is fine, as it's compatible with Apache v2). I recommend continuing to use the Apache v2 license. The license you choose to use should be placed in a file called `LICENSE` included in your project.

Again, I recommend consulting an attorney to ensure that you've met all requirements of the Apache license, before redistribution.